# Possible to Superclass a Dialog Box in Win32?

Tags: c++, windows, winapi

I'm using raw Win32 and C++ for a project. As I understand it, I am able to superclass Windows controls by retrieving the class information, replacing the procedure, then registering this as a new class and using it when creating a new window. Subclassing is done by replacing the window's procedure after the window is created. The advantage of superclassing is that you are able to process messages before `CreateWindow()` returns.

I'm looking to see if it's possible to superclass a dialog box created with `CreateDialog()` because I'd like to use a resource file for the dialog layout. The problem is that I don't know how I would provide my superclass when I create a dialog box. Is it even possible? Any idea how MFC handles this?

Comment: The source code for MFC ships with Visual Studio. MFC sets up a local CBT hook to get notified, when an `HWND` object is created, but before it is being used. That allows MFC to handle messages in the window procedure, including those that are passed to it while processing a `CreateWindow` call.

Comment: Awesome! This sounds like what I'd need.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you use an extended dialog box template to create your dialog, you can specify a custom window class as part of the [DLGTEMPLATEEX](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/dlgbox/dlgtemplateex) definition.

The dialog manager will create and layout your dialog as normal, and call your window procedure for any dialog messages. You can use the [DefDlgProc](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/winuser/nf-winuser-defdlgprocw) function to obtain default processing for any dialog messages you don't want to handle yourself.

Comment: Combined with the comment above, it sounds like I have all the solutions I need. Thanks!